# VGG network in pytorch produces identical outputs during test for different inputs

Tags: pytorch, vgg-net

I am using (untrained) VGG-19 with batch normalization on CIFAR10 images. When I turn the model into eval mode, I noticed that the model produced identical output logits values for different inputs. Is this normal? The parameters of the VGG network is random. Below is my code.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


cfg = {
    'vgg11': [64, 'M', 128, 'M', 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512, 'M'],
    'vgg13': [64, 64, 'M', 128, 128, 'M', 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512, 'M'],
    'vgg16': [64, 64, 'M', 128, 128, 'M', 256, 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 'M'],
    'vgg19': [64, 64, 'M', 128, 128, 'M', 256, 256, 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 512, 'M'],
}


class VGG(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vgg_name):
        super(VGG, self).__init__()
        self.features = self._make_layers(cfg[vgg_name])
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(512, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.features(x)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.classifier(out)
        return out

    @staticmethod
    def _make_layers(cfg):
        layers = []
        in_channels = 3
        for x in cfg:
            if x == 'M':
                layers += [nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)]
            else:
                layers += [nn.Conv2d(in_channels, x, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
                           nn.BatchNorm2d(x),
                           nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
                in_channels = x
        layers += [nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=1, stride=1)]
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)
```

Comment: On random parameters this shouldn't be the case. How exactly you're doing this, can you share the script?

Comment: Do you normalize the images before feeding to the net? is it possible that as a result of the random weights + image values you end up with hidden layers responses below ReLU threshold - thus resulting with the same logits for all inputs?